# What type of kernel density function does ArcMap use?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, density

I know that there are several types of kernel density functions, such as uniform, cosine, Gaussian, etc. I was just wondering which one the "Kernel Density" functionality in ArcMap 10's Spatial Analyst uses?

Comment: I reverse-engineered this many years ago (in Spatial Analyst 1.0); a detailed, illustrated explanation is at http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/GTKAV/section9/density.htm. Presumably it still applies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Silverman quadratic
"The kernel function is based on the quadratic kernel function described in Silverman (1986, p. 76, equation 4.5)."

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Kernel_Density_works/009z00000011000000/

The reference is to this book:

http://books.google.com/books?id=e-xsrjsL7WkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

on page 76, equation 4.5

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it uses quartic kernel function as below:

[image]

Where f(j) is the density at the center of the cell, h is Search Radius, dij is the distance between the incident point and center of the cell and n is the number of incidents within the search radius.